# Why passing T from outer template as default argument to std::function causes compilation error?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11

I create a template class, and pass the T as a default type argument. However this causes compilation failure. Anyone can explain what happens? Thank you!

PS. The compiler I use is VS2012.

```
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

template <typename T = void()>
struct delegate
{
    typedef function<T> function_t;

    function_t f;
};

int main()
{
    delegate<> d;

    return 0;
}
```

Compiler outputs:

```
1>.\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\functional(554): error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::_Get_function_impl<_Tx>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Tx=void (__cdecl *)(void)
1>          ]
1>          test.cpp(12) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::function<_Fty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Fty=void (__cdecl *)(void)
1>          ]
1>          test.cpp(17) : see reference to class template instantiation 'delegate<>' being compiled
1>.\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\functional(555): error C2504: 'type' : base class undefined
1>.\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\functional(558): error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::_Get_function_impl<_Tx>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Tx=void (__cdecl *)(void)
1>          ]
1>.\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\functional(558): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier '_Mybase'
1>.\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\functional(558): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Comment: Looks like an MSVC compiler bug. Compiles fine under g++ 4.7.0.

Comment: @Yuushi Oh really? Thank you very much. I was just wanting to make a default version of function<> which is equivalent to function<void()>.

Comment: The compiler is turning your `T` into a `void(*)()` instead of `void()`, then passing that to `std::function`, which is not a valid type to pass to `std::function`.  You could probably code a workaround that takes either `A(B...)` or `A(*)(B...)` as one argument and a `template<typename>class F` as the other and does `F<A(B...)>` if you really wanted to work around the issue.

Comment: @Yakk Hmm...are you sure that syntax `void()` has type `void(*)()` in the language standard? I might have come across an issue saying that it's not true with most compilers in practice.

Comment: Compiles fine with "Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)"

Comment: This is definitely a compiler bug. I have filed this in our internal database as DevDiv#671343.

Comment: @Patz Congrats - an admission from MS itself!

Answer (score 2):

As indicated by the comments on your question: This is just a bug in Visual Studio, not anything wrong with your C++ code. @Stephan-T-Lavavej says he's filed it as DevDiv#671343.

Assuming @Yakk's diagnosis is correct (MSVC incorrectly treating `T` as `void(*)()` instead of `void()`), I formerly proposed the "possible workaround" of

```
typedef function<typename remove_pointer<T>::type> function_t;
```

but as @JoshPeterson commented below, the bug still occurs in VS2013 even with that change, so it's not *actually* a workaround.

Comment: Using Visual Studio 2013 I replaced `typedef function<T> function_t;` with `typedef function<typename remove_pointer<T>::type> function_t;` and the problem still occurs.

Comment: I've just tried both the original problem and the proposed work around in Visual Studio 2013 Update 1. Still, neither will compile.